# Choice of voltage regulator for a battery powered Raspberry Pi Hat

Tags: integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi, buck, lipo

I'm building a robot controller hat for a Raspberry Pi 3B+ as an hobby.
I made a first working version using evaluation boards and prototyping boards.

Now I want to tighten the design and make a PCB that fits above the Raspberry Pi itself. This is a good moment and take a step back to reevaluate the design. I'd like help in choosing the voltage regulator IC as I feel there might be more fitting IC for my design that I don't know about.

**Specifications**

- VIN [9.6V - 16.8V]: Powered by a 3S/4S LIPO battery using an XT60 connector. 9.6V fully discharged 3S. 16.8V fully charged 4S battery.
- VOUT1 5.2V@3.0A: Powers the Raspberry Pi itself and a microcontroller.
- VOUT2 5.8V@3.0A: Powers a number of servomotors.

Additionally, I would like some additional features my current choice of voltage regulator doesn't have, and I would implement using external components.

- Temperature feedback: Would allow me to cut the servomotors and warn the Raspberry Pi if I'm taxing the voltage regulator.
- Output Current Feedback : Reading currents require more components, if there is a regulator that can do it, it would save space/components on the board. I'm thinking of using an ACS712-5 SOIC8 IC per each channel right now.
- Input/Output Voltage Feedback: Low priority since I can use a voltage divider and the ADC of the microcontroller. It's meant to detect battery low, and give an approximate measurement of battery life.

**Current Electronics**
I made a first working version using evaluation boards and prototyping boards.

[image: PRI+VoltageRegulator+Microcontroller and H-Bridges]

**Question**

I would like suggestions for dual channel non insulated voltage regulator IC.

Comment: MUST be a switching regulator for good efficiency. Well designed temperature should never be an issue.

Comment: the vnh7040 can do current sensing. no need for acs712.

Comment: As you say, vnh7040 gives current feedback for the DC motor. I want monitoring for the raspberry current and the servomotor current too.

Comment: @Russell McMahon I agree. I like to use a switching followed by a linear regulator for sensitive components, like micontroller with ADC. I'd like temperature monitoring on the regulator to monitor the temperature during operation and make sure all is right. I can do without though.

Comment: I'm using INA3221 for power sensing with a raspberry-pi host, you'll need to place a resistor for each high-side current sense channel. demo boards  are a few dollars from *online marketplace* or a few hundered from digikey.

Comment: Look at this part "LM27403" It has synchronous buck controller with temperature-compensated, inductor-DCR based overcurrent protection and programmable thermal shutdown. It is a nice part if you can work with the package.

Comment: @Gil From what I can see "LM27403" doesn't have a current sense output. I would like one to measure the current.

Comment: @Jasen The "INA3221" is promising. one IC and three shunts to measure current on three channels using a single communication line. An evaluation board might be good to try.

Comment: From the front page of the data sheet: LM27403 supports accurate and thermally compensated overcurrent protection (OCP). It is flagged on the PGOOD signal. It does require external connections but it is not documented well enough for you to use the CS pins. Sorry I thought you wanted protection,not to measure it.